# QMenu - shortcut is not triggered

Tags: qt, qtableview, qmenu, qaction

What is correct way to use QAction shortcuts? I have QTableView with custom context menu where beside other actions I want to have action `Refresh F5`:

```
// Popup
QAction *a;
a = mPopup.addAction(IconsManager::icon(fa::refresh), "Refresh", this, &UserPlaylistsSubWidget::refreshList, QKeySequence(Qt::Key_F5));
a->setShortcutVisibleInContextMenu(true);
```

First, I had to set `setShortcutVisibleInContextMenu` to make it visible in context menu but action is still not triggered when press F5 (QTableView is active and focused widget). Tried also different values for `QAction::setShortcutContext` but still no result.

Qt 5.12. Linux (KDE Neon)

Edit: Here is code which rise popup

```
connect(ui->list, &QWidget::customContextMenuRequested, this, &UserPlaylistsSubWidget::popUp);

void UserPlaylistsSubWidget::popUp(const QPoint &pos)
{
    mPopup.popup(ui->list->viewport()->mapToGlobal(pos));
}
```

Comment: Could you please show at least the code where you raise your `mPopup` menu?

Comment: Added code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Didn't know that QTableView has own actions list and can show it in own popup with `setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::ActionsContextMenu)`. So here is correct solution and F5 shortcut works as expected:

```
QAction *a = new QAction(IconsManager::icon(fa::refresh), "Refresh", ui->list);
a->setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_F5));
a->setShortcutVisibleInContextMenu(true);
connect(a, &QAction::triggered, this, &UserPlaylistsSubWidget::refreshList);
ui->list->addAction(a);
```